# React Native Bottom Navigation Custom Design

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, bottomnavigationview

Can you guys please help to design this kind of bottom navigation bar in React Native?

I am new to react-native.

[image: Refrece UI]

I have tried to find it on Google and on [React Native Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have indistinguishable view like that you can get refer from here

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const btns = ['btn 1', 'btn 2', 'btn 3', 'btn 4', 'btn 5']
const btnWidth = width / btns.length;
const activeColor = 'lightgreen'
const inactiveColor = 'white'
export default function AnimatedTabbarCurve() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(0)
    const translateX = useRef(new Animated.Value(active * width / btns.length)).current;
    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.spring(translateX, { toValue: active * btnWidth, useNativeDriver: true, bounciness: 0 }).start();
    }, [active])
    return (
        <View style={styles.flex}>
            <View style={styles.flex} />
            <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.bgContainer, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
                    <View style={styles.activeLeft}>
                        <View style={styles.activeLeftInner} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.activeBg} />
                    <View style={styles.activeRight}>
                    <View style={styles.activeRightInner} />
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>
                {btns.map((btn, i) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={btn} style={styles.btn} onPress={() => setActive(i)}>
                        <Text>{btn}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottom}>
                <Text>{active + 1}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    bottom: {
        height: height / 3,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: activeColor,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    btnContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: inactiveColor
    },
    btn: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 30,
    },
    bgContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        left: -btnWidth
    },
    activeBg: {
        width: btnWidth,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: activeColor,
        borderTopLeftRadius: btnWidth / 2,
        borderTopRightRadius: btnWidth / 2
    },
    activeRight: {
        width: btnWidth,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: activeColor,
    },
    activeRightInner: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        backgroundColor: inactiveColor,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: btnWidth / 2
    },
    activeLeft: {
        width: btnWidth,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: activeColor,
    },
    activeLeftInner: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        backgroundColor: inactiveColor,
        borderBottomRightRadius: btnWidth / 2

    }
})
```

and here is the view of that[image]